# CSS - Auto fill empty spaces with floating divs

Tags: css, css-float, html, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to create a grid layout at http://www.gablabelle.com/.

I have multiple divs (images) with float: left; property and I wonder why there is some empty spaces and why the floating divs are not filling the gaps.

Many thanks for your time and help.

**UPDATE:** I now use jQuery isotope but still have gaps... any idea?

Comment: You have to see the layout at gablabelle.com to understand.

Comment: See my comment in your duplicate (naughty!) question, maybe that way you can get what you want, albeit without masonry or Isotope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just how floating works. Those gaps are there because elements float after another breaks to a new line. It doesn't fill the space above.

If you want an uneven grid effect then you'd need to use a javascript solution where you are setting absolute positions. I'd recommend the [masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/), I think the before/after example on the homepage shows the problem you are having and the solution you want.

Comment: Damn ... OK I'll use the jQuery isotope plugin, but I wanted it to degrade nicely without javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I suggested masonry because it's free but I'm using isotope for a project right now too. Unfortunately there isn't a solution for this at the moment without using JS.

Comment: I still have gaps with isotope though. Check it out.

Comment: I don't see the gaps. It took a reload or two for it to work correctly though, check that you clear your cache, could be a browser issue. Also I noticed the no-js class is still applied on your html element after the JS fires. Though I'm not sure this would cause this error it's not impossible that it's a sign of other potential issues.

Comment: Resizing the browser does produce gaps though. You'll want to make sure you reinitialize the plugin with the correct settings not only when the page loads but also when it resizes.

Comment: Refresh and click on Nightlife.

Comment: Sadly that just seems to be a limitation of the plugin. The image of "Anne F" simply doesn't fit in the space above it. If you look at the examples on the isotope page sometimes there are still gaps in rare cases. Unless there is an isotope function to handle this I think your best bet is to limit how many large images like that you use. The more small images you have between large ones the easier it is to fill holes.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are looking for a way to fill all of the squares on the page. This isn't going to be possible simply through CSS. 'float: left;' is simply filling the space in the page, image by image, and not considering how it all fits together.

Fitting all of the pieces together so they sit cosily and like a jigsaw will not be easy. It is actually quite a complex problem, and it is connected to the knapsack problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and the packing problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem).

To solve this, I'm certain that there would be jQuery or JavaScript (or maybe even PHP) libraries available for use. Alternatively, you could manually order the photos such that they fit together in a tidy fashion.

Good luck!

Comment: OK I guess I'll just use the jQuery isotope plugin, but I wanted it to degrade nicely without any javascript.

Comment: A decent implementation of the Isotope plugin should handle this nicely. On a side note, the website you're designing looks pretty awesome!

Comment: Isotope is now on. But I still have gaps! Thanks it will be my new portfolio. Previous one was at visualise.ca. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is causing the gaps:

```
article.post {
    margin: 0 0 30px 30px;
}
```

Comment: No these are margins. I want that, I'm taking about the empty 270x270 spots.

Comment: @Gab: You can not get what you want by setting every float to left. Take "Karin et les feuilles" and set its float manually to right. The divs below will fit perfectly.